# Full Text Search Order By Query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
function _search($type, $qes, $sort = null, $start = 0) {
    $this->db
        ->select('id,name,frontCover,type,category,user,author,MRP,sellingPrice,isNew,isRaw,binding,publisherName,publicationYear')->from('books');
    $searchKey="";
    if(is_array($qes) && count($qes)>0){
        $searchKey = "+" . implode(" +", $qes);
    } 

    //full text search
    $searchKey = "MATCH name AGAINST ('".$searchKey."')";
    $this->db->where("(".$searchKey.")", NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('status',1)->limit(30, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query && $query->num_rows() ? $query->result() : [];

}
```

I am using full text search to find matched keywords. but it is not giving the correct answer. i need to get max matching searched comes first and then others.
it gives me random result. how to use order max keyword matched comes first?

Comment: your question isn't clear.

Comment: do you want to create a live search?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin yes just like that. i only need to get max matched words comes first.

Comment: why you don't use `$this->db->like('name',$field);`

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin if user search not proper word. i means you have written in comment __why you don't use__ if user search for __why you__ then like gives me proper result but if user searches for __ use why you__ then not searchable. i am using full text search it gives me result but not sorted like max matching words order first.

Comment: for sorting the result you cant use this `$this->db->order_by($field,'ASC');`